# Window.location Javascript JS Redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, window.location

I have this:

```
                setTimeout(function () {
              $.dialog({
                title: 'Existing user',
                content: "This account is already registered on our system. If you are the real owner, contact us!",
                icon: 'fas fa-user',
                theme: 'modern',
                animation: 'scale',
                type: 'red',
                draggable: false,
                closeIcon: function(){
                              window.location="/dashboard";
                          },
              });
            }, 200);
```

I need to redirect the user after 5 seconds once he/she clicks "closeIcon". The problem is, if I use this the dialog is never shown:

```
                    closeIcon: setTimeout(function () {
                              window.location="/dashboard";
                          }, 5000);
              });
```

How could I do?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I also tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
                function () {
              $.dialog({
                title: 'Existing user',
                content: "This account is already registered on our system. If you are the real owner, contact us!",
                icon: 'fas fa-user',
                theme: 'modern',
                animation: 'scale',
                type: 'red',
                draggable: false,
                closeIcon: setTimeout(function () {
                              window.location="/dashboard";
                          }, 5000);
              });
            }
```

Comment: because you are setting the closeIcon to a integer which is what the timeout returns.....

Comment: @epascarello Check my edit! Thanks.

Comment: Wrap the setTimeout() in a function ... `closeIcon: ()=>{ setTimeout(()=>window.location="/dashboard";})`

Comment: It needs to be like your first one with the timeout in there..... \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
closeIcon: function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
      window.location="/dashboard";
  }, 5000);
}
```

Do this instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setTimeout` [returns a positive integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), but the `closeIcon` expects a function. Using an [arrow function (ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to enclose the timer should fix the problem. You can also use a regular function.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $.dialog({
        title: 'Existing user',
        content: "This account is already registered on our system. If you are the real owner, contact us!",
        icon: 'fas fa-user',
        theme: 'modern',
        animation: 'scale',
        type: 'red',
        draggable: false,
        closeIcon: ()=> {
            setTimeout(()=>window.location = "/dashboard",2000);
        },
    });
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way of achieving this on a multilingual site, so that the "/dashboard" redirects to each specific language on the site?